# Is there a way to step through a RunJS app using the debugger in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm using [RunJS](https://github.com/pawelgalazka/runjs), a minimalist Javascript library for building executable tasks. I'd like to step through my code with the debugger in WebStorm. Is this possible or will JetBrains need to add support for RunJS in their Run Configuration Templates?

Comment: Yes, it is just JavaScript. You can set up a generic Nodejs run configuration and it will work fine. (I suspect this question will get zapped as off topic though).

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried that, but if I leave the executable as Node it doesn't invoke my command (because the node_modules/bin/run command is what has the logic to understand that what's exported from my runfile.js are tasks). But if I choose that run command as the interpreter, it doesn't understand the Node debug flag - I get: `Task --inspect-brk=52040 not found.`

Comment: Using Nodejs run config: Are you suggesting to me that you cannot set a break point in the `run.js` file and have execution stop at that breakpoint? That seems very odd.

Comment: Nevermind. RunJS uses `npx` which removes the ability to engage with the JavaScript environment. In this case, you'll need to write a JS file and execute it with `node` run config directly that runs `runFile.js` for you. That should work - but no, using `npx` will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **runjs-cli** (`npm install -g runjs-cli`) to run your tasks, you can use Node.js run configuration for debugging:

[image]

I'm not however sure how the scripts run with npx can be debugged...

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks!